# Getting 0 as sum of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

When I test my code I keep getting 0 as the sum and the average for the following code, yet it compiles. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class Array {
  int array[];
  int sum;

  Array(int[] array) {
    this.array = new int[10];

  }
  public int sum(){
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
         sum += sum + array[i];
      return sum;
    }
  public double average() {
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
         sum += sum + array[i];
      int average = sum / array.length;
      return average;
  }
}
```

Comment: `sum += sum + array[i];`? No. Either += or sum on the right side, but not both. Also, sum should be a local variable, not a field.

Comment: Also you never really show us the code initialising the array values. Are you sure it's not all zeroes? Use the debugger to find out.

Comment: Your sum will not include last element (check condition in `for` loops); Also each time you will invoke `sum()` you will increase value of class field so for array `{1,2,3,4}` `sum(); sum();` will first return `10`, then `20`.

Answer (score 7):

```
   Array(int[] array) {
     this.array = new int[10];      //The Problem is here

   }
```

use this

```
   Array(int[] array) {
      this.array = array;

   }
```

and change the sum to

```
  sum = sum + array[i];

  or

  sum += array[i];
```

Comment: and just for a better understanding I would suggest to not call the Constructors input parameter the same as the Class member. Maybe "inputArray" or something

Comment: +1 and while we're at it, don't name the class the same as a class in the JDK (an important one at that too)

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

- Your array as written holds only zeros.
- Your `sum += sum + array[i];` is not right. Either use `+=` or have sum on the right and use `=` but not both.
- Your average should cast either the numerator or denominator to double so you do double division not int division.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum += sum + array[i]
```

should be :

```
sum += array[i];
```

and on the for loop, you dont subtract 1 from length since you begin with index 0

it should be :

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     // additional logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Change

```
Array(int[] array) {
this.array = new int[10];
}
```

to

```
Array(int[] array) {
  this.array = array;
}
```

2.Change

```
 sum += sum + array[i];
```

to

```
sum += array[i];
```

3.Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You have some mistakes ...

```
public class Array {
    int array[];
    int sum;

    Array(int[] array) {
        this.array = new int[10];
        // this is write but wrong because if you are getting array of int as an argument then why you are not using it. here you can write like this
       // this.array = array;
    }
    public int sum(){
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
            sum += sum + array[i];
            // what is this? completely wrong logic for adding here you can use like this 
            // sum += array[i]   or you can use
            // sum = sum + array[i]
            return sum;
    }
    public double average() {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
            sum += sum + array[i];
            // same mistake again
            // one more point is if you have called sum() function then sum(variable) is already having adding of arrays that time you can not summing up again

            int average = sum / array.length;
            return average;
     }
}
```